# How to message everyone in a discord server with a certain role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am looking for a way to direct message everyone in a discord server using discord.py with a certain role with a custom message of my choice (Preselected) I have tried numerous different methods, none of which have worked. Please help me!

Comment: What exactly have you tried? \

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to DM everyone with a bot - discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45785727/how-to-dm-everyone-with-a-bot-discord-py)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over all the `Member`s on the `Server`, and check if they have the specified role.

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def message_role(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message):
    for member in ctx.message.server.members:
        if role in member.roles:
            await bot.send_message(member, message)

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

This would be invoked like

```
!message_role messageable Hi everybody!
```

That would send `Hi everybody!` to everyone with the `messageable` role.

Comment: i recieve this error discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Att
ributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'server'

Comment: Oops, that should be `ctx.message.server` I will edit my answer